# Mongoose populate virtuals producing 'undefined'

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, virtual, populate

I've created Mongoose virtuals with references on other Schemas before without issue, but I now have one that won't populate, and am unsure what to do.

```
        const InventorySchema = new mongoose.Schema(
      {
        name: { type: String }, 
        ............
    
      },
      {
        toJSON: { virtuals: true },
        toObject: { virtuals: true },
      }
    );
    
    InventorySchema.virtual('logs', {
      ref: 'Log',
      localField: '_id',
      foreignField: 'inventory',
    });


module.exports = mongoose.model('Inventory', InventorySchema);
```

And here's the Log Schema its referencing.

```
const LogSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
  {
    ...other info,
    inventory: {
      type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'Inventory',
    },
  },
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true },
  }
);

module.exports = mongoose.model('Log', LogSchema);
```

Calling the inventory.find results in undefined, despite records exsiting

```
const inventory = await Inventory.findById(req.params.id).populate('logs');
console.log(inventory.populated('logs'));      //undefined
console.log(inventory.logs);                   //undefined


const invLogs = await Log.find({ inventory: inventory._id });
console.log('invLogs: ', invLogs.length);      // 5 - so the records exist
```

I've searched on here but haven't seen an answer that works for me. I assume I'm doing something wrong, but I have similar virtuals on other collections. I should mention I'm using mongoose-autopopulate on Inventory, I haven't seen any issues with that and virtuals, but I could be wrong.

Answer (score 0):

According to the [mongoose documentation](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/tutorials/virtuals.html), the syntax for virtuals looks like this:

```
const userSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  email: String
});
// Create a virtual property `domain` that's computed from `email`.
userSchema.virtual('domain').get(function() {
  return this.email.slice(this.email.indexOf('@') + 1);
});
const User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);

let doc = await User.create({ email: 'test@gmail.com' });
// `domain` is now a property on User documents.
doc.domain; // 'gmail.com'
```

Specifically, note the call to `get()` and the parameter is a function that returns the value desired.

Comment: Thanks, but the mongoose populate-virtual gives this as an example: [link](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals).  It uses an object as the second argument to the virtual to reference another collection. `BandSchema.virtual("members", {
  ref: "Person",
  localField: "name",
  foreignField: "band",
  justOne: false,
});`